# libusb usb_bulk_read fails for Input/Output Error

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, device-driver, libusb, thermal-printer

I am evaluating a thermal printer. For this I wrote a USB driver based on libusb 0.1 in Linux and it works perfectly fine.

Now I am moving my platform to Windows. Here I use libusb-win32 0.1 . During this process I have installed filter for the printer I use.

In Windows, usb_bulk_write succeeds but usb_bulk_read fails due to Input/output error. Tested the same driver for another model of printer and usb_bulk_read works fine.

As the end-points are working fine in Linux, hope no question on end-points.

Comment: Can you post the code, and are you using common code for both platforms?

Comment: Depending on how serious you are, I would recommend getting a hardware USB protocol analyzer.  Or maybe check out the Microsoft Windows USB Core Team Blog, they have some information about software analysis of USB.

Comment: Preston, am using the same code for both platforms. Am just using the usb_bulk_read API.